# How to select Swift files that will be ported to ObjC using the bridge file?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using the .h bridge header file to use Swift classes on my ObjC project.
But none Swift file/header is being compiled into it, only default classes from the environment.

Look at the code from the header that is being generated:

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.51.1 clang-602.0.51)
#pragma clang diagnostic push

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<swift/objc-prologue.h>)
# include <swift/objc-prologue.h>
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wauto-import"
#include <objc/NSObject.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
# include <uchar.h>
#elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
#endif

typedef struct _NSZone NSZone;

#if !defined(SWIFT_PASTE)
# define SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y) x##y
# define SWIFT_PASTE(x, y) SWIFT_PASTE_HELPER(x, y)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_METATYPE)
# define SWIFT_METATYPE(X) Class
#endif

#if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_runtime_name)
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X) __attribute__((objc_runtime_name(X)))
#else
# define SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(X)
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA)
# define SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_CLASS)
# if defined(__has_attribute) &&  __has_attribute(objc_subclassing_restricted) 
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME)     __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted)) SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# else
#  define SWIFT_CLASS(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME)     SWIFT_CLASS_EXTRA
# endif
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_PROTOCOL)
# define SWIFT_PROTOCOL(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_RUNTIME_NAME(SWIFT_NAME) SWIFT_PROTOCOL_EXTRA
#endif

#if !defined(SWIFT_EXTENSION)
# define SWIFT_EXTENSION(M) SWIFT_PASTE(M##_Swift_, __LINE__)
#endif

#if !defined(OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER)
# if defined(__has_attribute) && __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif
#endif
#if !defined(SWIFT_ENUM)
# define SWIFT_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum     SWIFT_ENUM_EXTRA _name : _type
#endif
#if __has_feature(nullability)
#  define SWIFT_NULLABILITY(X) X
#else
# if !defined(__nonnull)
#  define __nonnull
# endif
# if !defined(__nullable)
#  define __nullable
# endif
# if !defined(__null_unspecified)
#  define __null_unspecified
# endif
#  define SWIFT_NULLABILITY(X)
#endif
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
#endif

#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wduplicate-method-arg"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

So, how can I choose the classes/files to be compiled into this header file, to use them in my Obj-C project ?
Thanks

## Edit

All of the Swift classes has @objc prefix and inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Perhaps the Swift classes are not "Objective-C compatible"? Do they inherit from NSObject or are they marked with @objc ?

Comment: Yes, all of them have the @objc prefix on the class and inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Another shot in the dark: The "Target Membership" check box is switched on for the Swift classes?

Comment: Yes, all the Swift files are in the target membership.

Answer (score 0):

A bridging header is not used to include Swift files in your Objective C files, it's the reverse.  Import your Objective C files into the bridging header and then you'll be able to use those classes in your swift files.

My header is called

```
SmartFusion-Bridging-Header.h
```

Inside I've imported something like so

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>
```

To import Swift into Objective C, let those bridges be generated automatically, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Instead, import this statement at the top of each of your Objective C files in which you want to include Swift classes.

```
#import <YourAppName-Swift.h>
```

Comment: Unless I am completely mistaken,  the contents of `<YourAppName-Swift.h>` is shown in the question, so OP is probably aware of that mechanism.

Comment: I think I have mistaken the name. I mean the generated interface header.
But anyway, I was already importing with #import "MYAPPNAME-Swift.h" in each file that I would use it.

Comment: @MartinR Unless it's explicitly stated in the OP's question, I have no problem stating the obvious.  Many a SO question have been answered this way.